# Replicating for...in loop with SpiderMonkey public API

Tags: javascript, for-loop, spidermonkey

I am trying to probe some JavaScript in SpiderMonkey (the latest release version) with the public C JSAPI.

How do I replicate the behavior of the `for...in` loop with public JSAPI calls, such as JS_GetPropertyById, JS_LookupProperty, JS_Enumerate, and others? The [documentation for JS_Enumerate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_Enumerate) says that it only returns enumerable properties on the target object; it does not search for properties in the object's prototype chain. I would like to replicate the exact behavior of the `for...in` loop, but avoid injecting code into the JS environment. It looks like JS_NewPropertyIterator may be deprecated, or is a strong candidate for deprecation.

Answer (score 1):

My first impression is that this probably isn’t a good thing to do. It is not something I would ever do because the behavior of `for...in` is kind of bizarre and idiosyncratic and I just don’t think it’s ever the right thing. But if this is really what you want, read on.

Internally, an actual `for...in` loop uses `js::ValueToIterator`, and that function doesn’t appear to be exposed via the JSAPI (at least jsapi.cpp doesn’t call it anywhere).  So you have two options:

1. Convince the Mozilla JS team to expose the `for...in` machinery via the JSAPI (if you were willing to help with the work, this is doable); or
2. Actually compile some JS code that has a `for...in` loop in it.

Option 2 will be quicker for you. You can use this function, for example:

```
function ForInResults(obj) {
    return [v for (v in obj)];
}
```

Or if you prefer an iterator:

```
function ForInIterator(obj) {
    for (var v in obj)
        yield v;
}
```

You can compile either of these functions using `JS_CompileFunction`, then call it using `JS_CallFunctionValue`. To get individual elements out of an array, use `JS_GetArrayLength` and `JS_GetElement`. Getting values out of an iterator is a little trickier, but it’s more like a real `for...in` loop in the unusual case where properties are being added or deleted while you’re looping.